# Selecting data with multi table SQL statement returns unexpected result

Tags: mysql, sql, select, csv, export

I want to format SQL results, then export to CSV (phpMyAdmin export).

SQL statement:

```
SELECT
product.name,
features.text
FROM products as product, product_features as features
WHERE
features.product_id=products.id LIMIT 0,100
```

Tables strucutre:

Table `products`:

```
------------
id | name
------------
24   Baseball
25   Rope
```

Table `product_features`:

```
--------------------------
id | text      | product_id
--------------------------
45   Leather..   24
46   Hardball    24
47   Nylon       25
48   Black       25
```

**Problem**: I get:

```
Baseball Leather
Baseball Hardball
Rope Nylon
Rope Black
```

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around what type of solution do with a SQL statement.

**Result I'm Looking for:**

```
Baseball, Leather..., Hardball
Basketball, Nylon, Black
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need some type of aggregate:

```
SELECT product.name, GROUP_CONCAT(features.text)
FROM products JOIN product_features ON(products.id = product_features.product_id)
GROUP BY products.id;
```

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks! Only change I had to make was removing the _ from "GROUP_BY".

Comment: Woops, don't know how that got in there -- fixed! (By the way, feel free to accept or upvote :-) )

Comment: shouldn't it be `GROUP BY product.name` ?

Comment: @Bohemian: Not really. The ID is what's getting matched.